# How to hide the redirected URL with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

is there any way to hide redirected url, here is what I think:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://minteddomain.com/mint/pepper/tillkruess/downloads/tracker.php?url=http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}&force
```

So the long redirected url http://minteddomain.com/mint/pepper/tillkruess/downloads/tracker.php?url=http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} to something shorter like /mintedomain.com/track/

It is possible?

Adrian

edit:

Andrew:

This is a stats software Mint (haveamint.com) with File Download tracker plugin. The File Download tracker works in this way:

in .htaccess every file (zip, rar, txt,...) is redirected to the tracker.php file (because the stats):
 http://mydomain.com/mint/pepper/tillkruess/downloads/tracker.php?url=http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

So the redirected url look like this for a zip file: http://minteddomain.com/mint/pepper/tillkruess/downloads/tracker.php?url=http://mydomain/downloads/apple.zip

This redirected URL is very long and ugly. The best for me would be to redirect this redirected URL to something shorter URL: example: http://mydomain.com/track/downloads/apple.zip..

So the http://mydomain.com/track would be the http://minteddomain.com/mint/pepper/tillkruess/downloads/tracker.php

Comment: My understanding was that (unless you add `[R]` to the `RewriteRule`) that `mod_rewrite` always hid the redirected URL from the user. Are you finding that, with the rule above, your users are seeing the longer, ugly URLs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to do.  Are you trying just to hide all the "ugliness" in the long URL and have http://minteddomain.com/track/www.example.com/whatever.html, which will then redirect to http://www.example.com/whatever.html?  Or, are you trying not to have the URL show that you are redirecting the user at all?